# how to send hidden input values of multiple images from view to controller in codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter-3

I want to pass hidden images name value to controller function and

in my view updt-project-details.php file, displaying multiple images in update page and also check for valid extension and show image, I also remove image using ajax and javascript, if not exist, I just display "no documents found" and if exist then display images, the code like this,

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-8">
       <input type="file" name="docs[]" multiple="multiple">
<?php $f = explode(',',$ans[0]->Proj_docs_path);
        foreach($f as $n){ if($n==''){ echo "<h4>No Documents Found.</h4>"; ?> <input type="hidden" name="p" value="<?php $arr=''; ?>"> <?php }else{ ?>      <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo base_url();?>images/project_docs/<?php echo $n; ?>">

        <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/<?php $azz = explode('.',$n);$ext = end($azz);if($ext=="pptx"||$ext=="ppt"){ ?>extensions_img/pptx.jpg<?php }elseif($ext=="pdf"){ ?>extensions_img/pdfimg.png <?php }elseif($ext=="docx"||$ext=="doc"){ ?>extensions_img/docximg.png <?php }elseif($ext=="xlsx"||$ext=="xls"){ ?>extensions_img/xlsx.png <?php }else{ ?>project_docs/<?php echo $n; }?>" style="margin:35px 25px;" height="100" width="100" class="img-thumbnail"><input type="hidden" name="p" value="<?php $arra = array(); $b = array_push($arra,$n);  ?>"></a>
        <a onclick="remove(<?php echo $m; ?> ,'<?php echo $n; ?>'); return confirm('Are You Sure to delete this!');" style="width:15px;height:15px;position: absolute;margin-left: -26px;margin-top: 10px;"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/x.png" style="width:15px;height:15px;position: absolute;margin-left: -26px;margin-top: 10px;"></a>
        <?php } }?>
   </div>
</div>
```

my controller Welcome.php file and function of the update

```
    public function projdetails_update($id)
{
$this->form_validation->set_rules('pcost','Project Cost','numeric');
if($this->form_validation->run()==false)
    {
        $d['m'] = $id;
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('updt-project-details',$d);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
    else
    {
       $cost = $this->input->post('pcost');
       $imghid = $this->input->get('p');
       if($imghid='')
       {
           // then update null value to image which updated successfully.
       }
        else
        {
            $data = array('img_path'=>implode($this->input->get('p'));
        }
    }
      // then update query which performs correctly.
}
```

how to take hidden values in an array and store it and then update it.
this is my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in updt-project-details.php file code i change as

```
      $arra = array();
      foreach($f as $key=>$n)
      {
          if($n=='')
           {
                   // updated as null
           }
          else
         {
          <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo 'p_'.$key;?>" value="<?php echo $arra[] = $n;  ?>">   
         }
```

it store values and i get it in controller.

Answer (score 0):

See what exactly it is happening is there are multiple images and your input tag name is overridden. You need to give dynamic image_name that is `img` tag name or your hidden value which you are storing image name.
Here is the way you can achieve it.

```
<?php
foreach($f as $key => $n)
{
    if($n=='')
    {
        //Your conditional code
    }
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo 'p_'.$key;?>" value="<?php $arra = array(); $b = array_push($arra,$n);  ?>">
<?php
}
?>
```

You can even take count in foreach but probably that is not needed.
You need to give dynamic name to hidden input.

After that in Your controller, you can simply do this

```
<?php
public function projdetails_update($id)
{
$this->form_validation->set_rules('pcost','Project Cost','numeric');
if($this->form_validation->run()==false)
{
    $d['m'] = $id;
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('updt-project-details',$d);
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
else
{
    print_r($_POST);
    //here you will get post variables of hidden values
}
```

Comment: i m sorry to reply so late, i did some another work, ok, i'll be try.. thanks i m new about it.

Comment: Sure, you can still appreciate my efforts by upvoting it :)

Comment: Array ( [cls] => 2 [pname] => nbfbfhg [tech] => Core PHP [ptype] => WebApp [stdt] => 2018-01-01 [endt] => 2018-01-02 [res] => Array ( [0] => Rohan [1] => Jenisha ) [pcost] => 5465 [status] => Under Review [p_0] => [reg] => Update ) , this is what return, p_0 addres is null, so not updated proper

Comment: maybe you are not getting the proper value